# Generating normal distribution in order python, numpy

Tags: python, numpy, normal-distribution

I am able to generate random samples of normal distribution in numpy like this.

```
>>> mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
>>> s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000)
```

But they are in random order, obviously. How can I generate numbers in order, that is, values should rise and fall like in a normal distribution.

In other words, I want to create a curve (gaussian) with mu and sigma and `n` number of points which I can input.

How to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you'd like, given some array of x-values, generate a set of y-values that are the values of the normal distribution at the x-values?

Comment: yes exactly what I want,, but I should be able to decide the number of points generated.

Comment: So, to be clear, you'd like to (1) generate a *random* sample of x-coordinates of size n (from the normal distribution) (2) evaluate the normal distribution at the x-values (3) sort the x-values by the magnitude of the normal distribution at their positions?

Comment: Yes that helps a lot, I got it now how to do from the steps.

Comment: If I post my answer, will you accept?

Comment: thanks, i only ask because i already wrote a code snippet to do this before I double-checked what you wanted!

Comment: Why do you need random samples?  It sounds like you just need a function that computes the probability density function (PDF) of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To (1) generate a random sample of x-coordinates of size n (from the normal distribution) (2) evaluate the normal distribution at the x-values (3) sort the x-values by the magnitude of the normal distribution at their positions, this will do the trick:

```
import numpy as np

mu,sigma,n = 0.,1.,1000

def normal(x,mu,sigma):
    return ( 2.*np.pi*sigma**2. )**-.5 * np.exp( -.5 * (x-mu)**2. / sigma**2. )

x = np.random.normal(mu,sigma,n) #generate random list of points from normal distribution
y = normal(x,mu,sigma) #evaluate the probability density at each point
x,y = x[np.argsort(y)],np.sort(y) #sort according to the probability density
```